# Definition of $\oplus_{i\in\mathbb I}R$ when $R$ is a module.

Tags: modules

Let $\{R_i\}_{i\in I}$ a collection of $M$ modules. I know that if $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$ is a basis of $\oplus_{i=1}^nR_i$, then, $$x\in \oplus_{i=1}^nR_i\iff \exists ! a_1,...,a_m\in M: x=a_1e_1+...+a_me_m.$$

Now, I have a definition when $I$ is unspecified, i.e. $$x\in \oplus_{i\in I}R_i\iff x_i=0\text{ except for a number finite of $i$}.$$

Is there a correlation between those two definitions ?

Comment: The first thing is the definition of being a basis and is unrelated to the direct sum (which may not even have a basis).

Comment: To me a logical definition of $x\in \oplus _{i\in I}R_i$ would be there is unique $x_i\in R_i$ s.t. $x=\sum_{i\in I}x_i$. Would that make sense ? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: You seem to be going about this in the opposite order of what is usual. We define the direct sum as a set, we don't usually write up what this means in terms of when something is an element of that set (because what sort of form would the element have to begin with anyway?).

Comment: Think about the sum $\mathbb{Z}_6\cong\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, does it make sense talk about a basis? Whatever it is it must be for both as they are isomorphic.

Comment: @ZelosMalum: What does mean $A\oplus B$ for groups ?